# Exploded by new line - unknown character

Tags: php, newline

I have this code:

```
$text = "Line 1

Line 3";

$n = explode("\r", $text);
```

If I echo `$n[1]` (line 2) I get a space. But `$n[1] == " "` returns `false`.

So what is the character?

## Update:

After further research, I should really be using:

```
$n = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $text);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line breaks can be `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n` depending on the OS and/or application that generated the new line

See [Newline#Representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations)

Comment: Yes, I needed `$n = explode("\r\n", $text);` so now `$n[1] == ""`

Answer (score 0):

The new line of your text is `\r\n`. So your string is:

```
$text = "Line 1\r\n\r\nLine 3";
```

and `explode("\r",$text)` make:

```
array("Line 1","\n","\nLine 3");
```

and `\n` is not equal to "" or " "

For historical reasons of why there are more than one new line representation see:

[Rationale of choosing difference new line representation by Unix, Mac, DOS/Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090113/rationale-of-choosing-difference-new-line-representation-by-unix-mac-dos-windo)